# How to post date and time to server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) library like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    <div id="searchContainer">

        <div class="well">
          <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
            <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="StartDate" />
            <span class="add-on">
              <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
              </i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
            <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="EndDate" />
            <span class="add-on">
              <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
              </i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>
}
```

This is another try:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    <div id="searchContainer">
        @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "datetimepicker1", @class = "input-append date" }).AppendIcon("icon-calendar")
        @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "datetimepicker2", @class = "input-append date" }).AppendIcon("icon-calendar")

        @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en'
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en'
            });
        });
</script>
```

The first chunk of code where the divs are used, work fine when selecting a date and time. But the second one with the razor syntax doesn't.

When using the first chunk for selecting a date and time, it's not posted to the server when button is pressed.

The model only contains the 2 dates:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

With "it doesn't work" when using the Razor syntax, the datetimepicker just didn't show up, nothing happened. Now I have been testing some further, i get a runtime error pointing to this line in the datetimepicker.min.js file:

> offset.top=offset.top+this.height;

And this is the error message it pops up in a dialog:

> Unhandled exception at line 26, column 5290 in
>   http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of
>   undefined or null reference

This is the rendered html of the form:

```
<form action="/Home/Search" method="post">    <div id="searchContainer">
        <select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Select items" id="Ids" multiple="multiple" name="Ids"><option value="1">test0</option>
<option value="2">test1</option>
<option value="3">test2</option>
<option value="4">test3</option>
<option value="5">test4</option>
<option value="6">test5</option>
</select>
        <div class="input-append"><input class="input-append date" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Start Date field is required." id="datetimepicker1" name="StartDate" type="text" value="1-1-0001 0:00:00" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>
        <div class="input-append"><input class="input-append date" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field End Date must be a date." data-val-required="The End Date field is required." id="datetimepicker2" name="EndDate" type="text" value="1-1-0001 0:00:00" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>



        <button class="btn   btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en'
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en'
            });
        });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #searchContainer {
        margin-top:10%;
}
</style>

</div> 

  <div id="push"></div>
</div>

  <div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
     <p>&copy; 2013 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my model to accept a `string` instead of a `DateTime` object, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach has the problem, that you omitted the name attributes for the input fields. The name attribute defines what variable is posted by the form.
Just write :

```
<input ... type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate />
```

For your second try:

> But the second one with the razor syntax doesn't.

What do you mean with *doesn't work*? Can you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: got the divs working yesterday. Somehow I forgot to use the 'name' attribute, and in stead i used 'id'. But i've updated my original post with why the razor syntax version doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For the second try:

If you look at the documentation for [bootstrap datetime-picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), it shows that the `id` attribute `#datetimepicker1` should be applied to the container of the input. Instead you are applying it to the input itself.

Also it seems that attributes `data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"` need to be applied to the `<i>` tag, which TwitterBootstrapMVC does not do out of the box.

Either submit an issue to the [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc) to add an overload to `.IconAppend` method to also take `Icon` class that you'd be able to customize however you want... or better yet, fork it make the necessary change and submit a pull request.